# Marketing Cloud System Personalization Strings for SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect, sms

Are there any AMPSscript personalization strings to identify an individual send available in Marketing Cloud's MobileConnect SMS sends? What I'm looking for is something along with the following available in Email Studio:

- `%%jobid%%`
- `%%_emailid%%`
- `%%emailname_%%`

Alternatively, I'd like to utilize either the MobileMessageTrackingID or Campaign Name / Campaign Code.

Is there a way to include these in the SMS? The use case is to enter them in a parameter of the URL within the message in order to track the performance of individual SMS sends. Something like this:

```
Click here! http://example.com/?utm_medium=sms&utm_source=%%MobileMessageTrackingID%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no equivalents of those strings in Mobile Connect yet.

The only solution for now is to manually declare the data you're interested in as separate variables and concatenate them into the UTM link which could look something like this:

```
%%[
    set @source = "sfmc"
    set @medium = "sms"
    set @campaign = "info"
    set @link = Concat("http://example.com/?utm_source=", @source, "&utm_medium=", @medium, "&utm_campaign=", @campaign)
]%%

Click here: %%=v(@link)=%%
```